# installing git, which git version is ok, and a $path Q

Tags: git

it’s been a while since i installed git.
i found install options provided from git-scm/download/mac at sourceforgedotcom but it specifically references mavericks which isn't my OS.
if i click big green btn i get 2.15.0 version. previously i used dmg installations and can learn others but need help, please.

i’m not sure i’m ready for homebrew. i def want to learn but have my plate full at this point. ditto for macports.
i’d like to embrace and be confident w terminal/shell.. hence, not interested in desktopGUI until later.

i’ve already installed Xcode but latest git version is 2.27.0 and i got apple’s which is 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128).

Qs:

is sourceforgedotcom ok to download dmg and which one do i select?

is it necessary that i have the latest git version or will apple’s 2.24.3 suffice?

my current version is located in usr/bin/git… should i change $path to usr/local/bin/git.. does it matter?

how does one install git from ‘source’ using a tarball—the curl command, clone? i'd like to learn.

thank you!! <3

Comment: https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: If you have an older git installed, it might be simplest to clone  git@github.com:git/git.git and build from there.  It's basically `autoreconf -ivf; ./configure --prefix=$HOME; make; make install`  (YMMV)

Comment: thank you, @WilliamPursell. i'm not comfortable executing autoreconf since this looks advanced and i'm very inexperienced.
further research indicates sourceforgedotcom is legit link.
still hoping for answers to Qs 2,3 and if there are any beginner level articles/tutorials on installing tarball. cheers

Comment: autoreconf is safe to run.  All it will do is generate some files in your working directory.  But it is totally responsible to be wary of building from git, and building from the tarball is probably the right thing to do.

Comment: @WilliamPurcell thanks for your continued replies. as i said, i’m not comfortable executing your example however safe i’m sure it is, sorry. still hoping for answers to Qs 2,3 and if there are any beginner level articles/tutorials on installing tarball. cheers